# Session Token to SPA Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, single-page-application

We are rebuilding an ASP.NET Web form based app to SPA with Angular and ASP.NET MVC. On the target state, User auth is managed through SSO from MVC action filters. After successful User authentication, the User details (role, ID, GUID) are required to retain in user session and share with client (angular component and view binding) to show the user details in app header. What would be the recommended technical approach to maintain the user session between SPA and ASP.NET MVC?

I assume that a model (with UserID, Role, GUID) can be generated and shared from API controller to SPA (controller) in JSON format post successful authentication. So that, the user session of SPA can retrieve/submit API requests with given GUID as session_identifier. On every request from client to API controller, session_identifier can be verified against the GUID in User Context. If session context in Server side is still holding the same GUID then the client's request will be processed. Otherwise request will be denied and redirected to SSO again. Is it an architecturally valid approach?

Please note, IIS server will be configured for 30 mins Idle timeout.

Comment: JWT tokens: https://code-maze.com/authentication-aspnetcore-jwt-1/

Comment: @harishr Thanks much for sharing an appropriate link. It explains clearly how to handle my needs. In summary, after successful authentication, server controller need to generate an encoded JWT and send to client. This should be stored in local storage and send back to server by client page on every get /post request and then the Server need to validate it. Would that be enough to meet client side security? or does client need to validate for any reason?

Comment: that is enough.. security has to be always serverside and not clientside